# Removing all values but the first from a drop down list using jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc

```
             if (questions[0]) {
                 $("select[id$=ddlPollQuestions] > option").remove();
                 $('#ddlPollQuestions').append('<option value="">Choose a question to compare to</option>');
                 $.each(questions, function(i, question) {
                     $('#ddlPollQuestions').append('<option value="' + question.QUESTIONID + '">' + question.TEXT + '</option>');
                 });
             } else {
                 $("select[id$=ddlPollQuestions] > option").remove();
                 $('#ddlPollQuestions').append('<option value="' + 0 + '">' + 'There are no questions of this type' + '</option>');
             }
```

What this does is it removes all the previous values, But i want my first option, which is "Choose a question ..." to remain, and then display "There are not questions..." as my 2nd option. My code here does not show "Choose a question.." as the first option. Thanks for having a look!

Comment: Could you make a jsFiddle example?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [:gt](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/) selector.

Try this(Note that I have added a string variable to append the options after the each loop for better performance):

```
if (questions[0]) {
         $("select[id$=ddlPollQuestions] > option:gt(0)").remove();
         $('#ddlPollQuestions').append('<option value="">Choose a question to compare to</option>');
         var options = "";
         $.each(questions, function(i, question) {
            options += '<option value="' + question.QUESTIONID + '">' + question.TEXT + '</option>';
         });
         $('#ddlPollQuestions').append(options);
 } else {
         $("select[id$=ddlPollQuestions] > option:gt(0)").remove();
         $('#ddlPollQuestions').append('<option value="' + 0 + '">' + 'There are no questions of this type' + '</option>');
 }
```

Answer (score 27):

An easier approach:

```
$('#ddlPollQuestions').children('option:not(:first)').remove();
```

Comment: short and nice solution

Answer (score 0):

since you are removing all the options in your code, you'll might just want to append again the `Choose a question...` in your `else` statement

```
if (questions[0]) {
    $("select[id$=ddlPollQuestions] > option").remove();
    $('#ddlPollQuestions').append('<option value="">Choose a question to compare to</option>');
    $.each(questions, function(i, question) {
        $('#ddlPollQuestions').append('<option value="' + question.QUESTIONID + '">' + question.TEXT + '</option>');
    });
} else {
    $("select[id$=ddlPollQuestions] > option").remove();
    $('#ddlPollQuestions').append('<option value="">Choose a question to compare to</option>');
    $('#ddlPollQuestions').append('<option value="' + 0 + '">' + 'There are no questions of this type' + '</option>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

example: http://jsfiddle.net/xeYwv/2/

```
var $PollQuestions = $('#ddlPollQuestions');

if (questions[0]) {
    $PollQuestions.children().remove();
    $PollQuestions.append('<option value="0">Choose a question to compare to</option>');
    $.each(questions, function(i, question) {
        $PollQuestions.append('<option value="' + question.QUESTIONID + '">' + question.TEXT + '</option>');
    });
} else {
    $PollQuestions.children().remove();
    $PollQuestions.append('<option value="' + 0 + '">' + 'There are no questions of this type' + '</option>');
}
```

what you had is already pretty close.